# Lightweight snmp check for printer toner status

Tags: networking, snmp, printer

i hope this is the right site to post this question.

First of all in my organization we have a lot of HP network printers (2015 and 2055) all have static ip configured and SNMPv2 up and running.
I'm looking for a lightweight tool that allows me to monitor the toner status of these printers.

Spiceworks do the job but IMHO has too many features and it's all except lightweight. I'd like to run it in a Linux VM with 512 Mb Ram (if possibile).
I checked out Nagios, Cacti, Zabbix, Zenoss and many other i don't recall the name but all of these tools are studied to check uptime or route status.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try www.opennms.org  You will have to do some amount of custom coding for your printers, but that's unavoidable no matter what platform you choose.  Are you planning to  check with SNMP traps (they send a trap when toner is low) or check it with SNMP reads (you read it every X minutes)?  I also found this, which may be of assistance: http://forums.cacti.net/about2771.html

Comment: I would like to check with SNMP reads. I'll give a try to opennms.
However with the help of a friend i'm writing a specific tool to check printers toner status in Java... nothing too complex just a simple, crossplatform and lightweight tool (No need to run VMs etc).

Comment: @eldblz, did you ever write that java tool?

Comment: I'm using spicework... it's bloated but does the job.